# Lifetime struggles with "borrowed value does not live long enough" for lazy_static value

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Rust newbie here that has been struggling for a full day on how to get the compiler to recognize that the lifetime of a lazy_static struct instance is 'static.  A minimal example of what I am trying to do is the following:

```
use redis::{Client, Connection, PubSub};
use std::sync::Mutex;

#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static ref REDIS_CLIENT: Mutex<Client> =
        Mutex::new(Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1/").unwrap());
    static ref RECEIVER_CONNECTIONS: Mutex<Vec<Connection>> = Mutex::new(vec![]);
    static ref RECEIVERS: Mutex<Vec<PubSub<'static>>> = Mutex::new(vec![]);
}

pub fn create_receiver() -> u64 {
    let client_instance = match REDIS_CLIENT.lock() {
        Ok(i) => i,
        Err(_) => return 0,
    };

    let connection: Connection = match client_instance.get_connection() {
        Ok(conn) => conn,
        Err(_) => return 0,
    };

    let mut receiver_connections_instance = match RECEIVER_CONNECTIONS.lock() {
        Ok(i) => i,
        Err(_) => return 0,
    };

    let receiver_connection_index = receiver_connections_instance.len();
    receiver_connections_instance.push(connection);

    let receiver_connection = &mut receiver_connections_instance[receiver_connection_index];
    let receiver = receiver_connection.as_pubsub();

    let mut receivers_instance = match RECEIVERS.lock() {
        Ok(i) => i,
        Err(_) => return 0,
    };

    receivers_instance.push(receiver);
    let receiver_handle = receivers_instance.len();

    receiver_handle.try_into().unwrap()
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `receiver_connections_instance` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:33:36
   |
33 |     let receiver_connection = &mut receiver_connections_instance[receiver_connection_index];
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
34 |     let receiver = receiver_connection.as_pubsub();
   |                    ------------------------------- argument requires that `receiver_connections_instance` is borrowed for `'static`
...
45 | }
   | - `receiver_connections_instance` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I don't understand this because RECEIVER_CONNECTIONS is a lazy_static variable and I don't think my code uses the `receiver_connections_instance` past the end of the function.

Many thanks and infinite karma to whoever can help me understand what I'm doing wrong here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `Connection` isn't `'static` at the time you invoke `as_pubsub()`, you access it through a mutex guard with a limited lifetime. As soon as you drop the guard, the connection is no longer exclusively yours, and neither is the `PubSub` - which is why `PubSub<'static>` is not allowed. The redis Rust API doesn't seem to allow *exactly* what you're after (at least without unsafe), because `Connection::as_pubsub()` requires `&mut self`, prohibiting you from invoking `as_pubsub()` directly on a globally stored `Connection`.

But since your connections are global and never removed anyway, you could simply not store the connection, but "leak" it instead and only store the `PubSub`. Here *leak* is meant in a technical sense of creating a value that is allocated and then never dropped, much like a global variable, not to an uncontrolled memory leak that would indicate a bug. Leaking the connection gives you `&'static mut Connection` which you can use to create a `PubSub<'static>`, which you can store in a global variable. For example, this compiles:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref REDIS_CLIENT: Client = Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1/").unwrap();
    static ref RECEIVERS: Mutex<Vec<PubSub<'static>>> = Default::default();
}

pub fn create_receiver() -> RedisResult<usize> {
    let connection = REDIS_CLIENT.get_connection()?;
    let connection = Box::leak(Box::new(connection)); // make it immortal

    let mut receivers = RECEIVERS.lock().unwrap();
    receivers.push(connection.as_pubsub());
    Ok(receivers.len() - 1)
}
```

Several tangential notes:

- redis `Client` doesn't need to be wrapped in `Mutex` because `get_connection()` takes `&self`.
- you don't need to pattern-match every mutex lock - locking can fail only if a thread that held the lock panicked. In that case you most likely want to just propagate the panic, so an `unwrap()` is appropriate.
- using 0 as a special value is not idiomatic Rust, you can use `Option<u64>` or `Result<u64>` to signal that a value could not be returned. That allows the function to use the `?` operator.

The code above has these improvements applied, resulting in a significantly reduced line count.

Comment: Thank you so much - this in combination with the other answer really helped my understanding of how this all works in Rust.

Answer (score 1):

The TLDR is that the relevant reference is not `'static` because it's tied to the lifetime of the mutex guard. I'll explain the issue by walking through the relevant parts of the code.

You start by locking the `RECEIVER_CONNECTIONS` mutex, storing the guard in `receiver_connections_instance`:

```rust
let mut receiver_connections_instance = match RECEIVER_CONNECTIONS.lock() {
    Ok(i) => i,
    Err(_) => return 0,
};
```

Then you get a mutable reference to data inside the guard, and store it in `receiver_connection`:

```rust
let receiver_connection = &mut receiver_connections_instance[receiver_connection_index];
```

You then call the `as_pubsub()` method on `receiver_connection` and store the result in `receiver`:

```rust
let receiver = receiver_connection.as_pubsub();
```

The signature of that `as_pubsub()` method is the following:

```rust
fn as_pubsub(&mut self) -> PubSub<'_>
```

which if we un-elide the lifetimes can be written as

```rust
fn as_pubsub<'a>(&'a mut self) -> PubSub<'a>
```

We can see from the lifetimes that the return type `PubSub` captures the input lifetime. (This is because `PubSub` stores the mutable reference inside itself). So all of this means the lifetime of `receiver` is bound to the lifetime of the mutex guard. The code that follows then tries to store `receiver` in the static `RECEIVERS` variable, but that cannot work because `receiver` cannot outlive the mutex guard `receiver_connections_instance`, which is dropped at the end of the function.

Comment: Thank you so much - this in combination with the other answer really helped my understanding of how this all works in Rust.